# Temporal demultiplexing of a single 5 V trigger signal to three outputs

Tags: circuit-design

I’m a logic circuit newbie and would be grateful for all the help I can get. I’m struggling to find the answer since I’m not sure what keywords to use when googling.

I have a square wave trigger signal at 60 Hz that I would like to split into three different outputs like:

```
Input:
__—-__—-__—-__—-__—-__
Out 1
__—-__________—-______
Out 2
______—-__________—-__
Out 3
__________—-__________
```

How can I achieve something like this? I guess I would need some sort of frequency divider but how can I get the pulses into the three different outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original 14/02/22 started with: *It looks like homework or an assignment so you can have guidance but not an answer. Otherwise, you learn nothing.* OP since stated they're a researcher in lasers so answer revised...

You can use a 3-DFF ring counter and three AND gates to do this, as shown below.

During reset, the ring counter is loaded with '100'. The counter DFFs clock inputs are falling-edge triggered. So at the end of every pulse, the ring counter contents are rotated by one position. Only one counter bit is ever 1, the rest are zero, making its DFF outputs 'one hot'.

The ring counter enables only one AND gate for flow-through of the pulse at any time. Advancing the ring counter on the pulse falling edge ensures that you don't get glitches on the AND gate outputs. That's reliant on the ring counter pulse-to-/CLK connections having less propagation delay (shorter, lower impedance) than the pulse-to-AND connections.

There are plenty of voltage supervisor ICs around for you to select from, by firms like TI and Maxim. This will assert its active-LOW /RST output while its connected supply is below a specified voltage threshold. A short while (reset period) after the rail is above the threshold, /RST is negated and the ring counter can function.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fESJIn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You don't specify a logic voltage standard. If 3.3 V, it may be simpler to use a CPLD to implement this circuit. It's about twenty lines of VHDL plus the free development software. You can then buy a cheap CPLD demo' board with pins to connect directly to. If in a CPLD, the ring counter output-to-input term can be implemented as a state table so any concerns about the miniscule chance of the ring counter corrupting its pattern can be eradicated. And the pulse-to-/CLK requirement above can easily be designed for and met. Otherwise, the circuit above is just four ICs.

Comment: Ok thanks for your input! I'm actually a researcher (not in electronics obviously, but lasers) and would like to trigger my three different lasers at 20 Hz each to match a forth laser which operate at 60Hz... I hope I'll be able to figure out a solution with your hints, If not I'll come back for more;-)